# How is MD5 hash of a blobstore blob encoded on Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, md5, blobstore

On the development server, after uploading a blob to blobstore, BlobInfo.getMd5Hash() returns a String (why not just the binary hash?) that seems to be the hex encoded hash value. I can proof this true with hashing the file locally.
However on Appengine getMd5Hash() returns something different.
It seems to be Base64 encoded, but decoding it with Base64 does not match with what I get locally. Maybe it uses a different hashing algorithm, too?
Which encoding is used and why is it not consistent on development and production?

Any help appreciated.